# How i can pass parameter from view to controller

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade

How i can get data from view and send it to controller
for example

```
$banner['Top-right']
```

how i can send "Top-right" to controller to select all banner in this location

```
//$location = Top-right
$banner=Banners::where('location',$location)->first();
```

Comment: First of all show us some code. What you have. You can send data to controller by `get`, `post` or using `ajax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have find a solution for my problem maybe help anyone in future

in View

```
@php
  $bannersTopright=App\Models\Banners::where('status','1')->where('location','Top-right')->first();
@endphp

<img src="{{Storage::url('images/banners/cache/'.$bannersTopright->image)}}" alt="{{$bannersTopright->name}}">
```